# Extract a certain part of a file and write into a new file

Tags: python-3.x

I want to extract a certain part of a file (in txt format), but these parts will repeat several times. I'd like to extract all of these and write them into a new file.

For example: 
This is a text file, it has some different patterns.

aaaaaa

\begin{theorem} aaaaaaaaaa \end{theorem}

bbbb

\begin{theorem}

aaaaaaaaaa

\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem} aaaaaaaaaa

\end{theorem}

I want to extract all lines between every \begin{theorem} and \end{theorem} including \begin{theorem} and \end{theorem}, and then write them in a new text file. Here is a code I've tried but will output nothing in my writing file.

```
inFile = open("infile.txt")
outFile = open("outfile.txt", "w")
keepCurrentSet = False
for line in inFile:
    if line.startswith("\end{theorem}"):
        keepCurrentSet = False
    index +=1
    if keepCurrentSet:
        outFile.write(line)

    if line.startswith("\begin{theorem} "):
        keepCurrentSet = True
        index1 +=1
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Post a code that haven't work for you. StackOverflow is here to help you, not to do the whole work for you.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by regex. I am not putting code for reading and writing a text file, assuming you know this part!!

```
##text = Your text file in this variable
import re
p =r'(\bHeadingA\b.*?\bHeadingB\b)' ## Write the name of actual "A" and "B" from which you need to extract text in place of HeadingA and HeadingB
m =re.findall(p, text, re.I|re.M|re.DOTALL)
print(m)  ## Write m in any new text file
```

Comment: Can you post your version of 'p' here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Regular Expressions ([documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re)).

**Divide the problem in parts.**

As with every problem in programming, you should divide it into smaller problems. In your case I would do it in the following way:

**1.** Find the occurrences of the words you need.

**2.** Get the range between each appearance.

**3.** Copy the text to a new file.

Let's solve it by parts:
In order to **find occurrences** you can use the `find()` method in regex (short for Regular Expressions). This will tell you the index of each time your word appears. You should do this separately for A and B, so you know where is each.

**Note:** A more advanced way of doing this is to build a regex like the following: `(A)(*)(B))`, as this will match everything between an appearance of A and one of B. This is also easier.

As for the second and third steps, they are pretty much straight forward once you have understood the first one.

Good luck!